# Error while implementing HATEOAS in Spring Boot Application : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I am working on the spring-boot application and I created a small application for User management and have operation like get-user, create-user etc. These operations were working fine until I used HATEOAS. Now I am getting below error when hit my web-service from POSTMAN.

Erro in POSTMAN :

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-05-17T16:01:22.049+00:00",
"message": **"Object of class [java.util.ArrayList] must be an instance of interface org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.LastInvocationAware"**,
"details": "uri=/user/get-user/100",
"className": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
```

}

Path I am using to access the web-service : http://localhost:8080/user/get-user/100

I do have a user with id 100 in my static list and have no errors in the compilation.

Here is my @RestController annotated class :

```
all required imports here >

@RestController
 public class UserResource {

@Autowired
private UserDaoService service;

@GetMapping(path = "/user/get-users")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return service.getUserList();
    
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/user/get-user/{id}")
public EntityModel<User> getUserByIDWithURL(@PathVariable int id) {

    System.out.println("Request for ID: " + id);
    User user = service.findUser(id);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found with ID " + id);
    }

    EntityModel<User> resource = EntityModel.of(user);
    WebMvcLinkBuilder link = linkTo(this.getAllUsers());
    resource.add(link.withRel("all-users"));

    return resource;
}


}
```

Note: UserDaoService have the static list of users and this class provides various operation such as getting all users, deleting user from list etc.

Looking forward to get the solution as earliest so that I could progress with my App. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you send the code for UserDaoService ? I remember I had same issue and then it got solved. Please also review below line, this looks suspicious.

```
WebMvcLinkBuilder link = linkTo(this.getAllUsers());
```

Comment: here you go : https://github.com/borkarda/spring-boot-repo/blob/main/UserDaoService.java

Comment: OK. try this : WebMvcLinkBuilder link = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getAllUsers());